prerequisite for painting a wood window
I am living in a cold country and I have an old windows that really need some care. I have bought the basic materials that I thought would be needed like paint(for outdoor use) and sand paper and window Caulk and as I was about to start my DIY repair I came across another product that people are suggesting to use prior to painting which is called "primer". I didn't know about this product at all and I am wondering how important it is to paint the window with "primer" before putting the final paint.
if I use primer do I still need to buy wood oil and oil the window before painting?
the window has an old paint on it which I would need to remove.



Not a professional painter here, but I think you use wood oil if the wood is stained and not painted.  However, things can be different outside the U.S.  Also needing primer depends on the condition of the old paint,   The painting pros will let us know for sure.  Some pics would help .

@RMDman, I added picture, thank you.

"Wood oil" is a different type of finish than paint. Such penetrating products soak in and provide an internal water resistance and rich appearance. Paint is a coating, which remains on the surface. You should not be using a penetrating product on previously painted wood.
Whether you need primer depends on the type of paint you'll apply and what you'll apply it to. Primer seals porous surfaces and provides a bonding surface. If you're overcoating a compatible paint, and if you aren't scraping and sanding so much that significant areas of raw wood are exposed, it probably isn't needed.
The key is to read the label on your paint. It'll make it very clear what preparation is needed and what surfaces are appropriate for a good bond.
